# Apply to all function in hash table not working

Tags: c, unit-testing, hashtable, void-pointers

I'm trying to create a function which applies an input to all entries in a hash table. The example shown here is for inputting the same value on all areas of the hash table. I got it working the other day but now it seems to always fail (no clue what has been changed) and the versions in my github history all share the same issue. When debugging using gdb I can see that in my test the application is not occuring and all entries remain at NULL. Can anyone see what might be wrong with my code?

The function being tested:

```
void hash_table_apply_to_all(hash_table_t *ht, apply_function apply_fun, void *arg)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < No_Buckets; i++)
    {
        entry_t *current_entry = (&ht->buckets[i])->next;
        while (current_entry != NULL)
        {
            apply_fun(current_entry->key, &current_entry->value, arg);
            current_entry = current_entry->next;
        }
    }
}
```

The applied value insert function:

```
void value_insert(int key_ignored, char **value, void *x)
{
    *value = (char *) x;
}
```

The unit test (CUnit):

```
void test_apply_to_all()
{
    hash_table_t *ht = hash_table_create();
    char *valtest = "a";
    bool result = NULL;
    hash_table_apply_to_all(ht, value_insert, valtest); // here I am trying to apply the value "a" to all entries
    for (int i = 0; i < No_Buckets; i++)
    {
        hash_table_lookup(ht, i, &result);
        if (!result)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    CU_ASSERT_TRUE(result);
    hash_table_destroy(ht);
}
```

Structs

```
struct entry
{
    int key;       // holds the key
    char *value;   // holds the value
    entry_t *next; // points to the next entry (possibly NULL)
};

struct hash_table
{
    entry_t buckets[No_Buckets];
};
```

Typedef of apply function:

```
typedef void(*ioopm_apply_function)(int key, char **value, void *extra);
```

Lookup function

```
char *hash_table_lookup(ioopm_hash_table_t *ht, int key, bool *result)
{
  entry_t *tmp = find_previous_entry_for_key(&ht->buckets[key % No_Buckets], key);
  entry_t *next = tmp->next;
  if (tmp && tmp->next != NULL)
  {
    next = tmp->next;
  }
  if (next && next->value)
  {
    *result = true;
    return (next->value);
  }
  else  
  {
    *result = false;
    return (NULL);
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you create the hash_table ht ? Can you show the code ?

Comment: @PtitXav `hash_table_t *hash_table_create()
{
  hash_table_t *result = calloc(1, sizeof(hash_table_t));
  return result;
}`

Comment: You create a hash_table wit all memory set to 0 : next is NULL : you never append something to next.

Comment: @Ptit Xav How do I solve this in my function?

Comment: It looks like you are applying to all on an empty hash table? Maybe populate it with entries?

Comment: can you paste `hash_table_lookup()`?

Comment: @tstanisl Added it :)

Comment: What is supposed to be in the entry list ? In your test you do not create any entry .

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is line:

```
 entry_t *current_entry = (&ht->buckets[i])->next;
```

It means that you miss the first element in the bucket chain which is `ht->buckets[i]` itself. You start from its successor.

Does changing to:

```
entry_t *current_entry = &ht->buckets[i];
```

help?

Comment: No sadly it doesnt, the reason it starts at next is because the first entry is a dummy.

Comment: @davdavdav2, ok. It's a bit wasteful though. Consider making `buckets` an array of pointers to `entry_t`